# is it possible to easily merge two files like this in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2, fedora20

I have two files, the first one contains this:

```
companyName
url
country
address
zip
founders
industry
isPrivate
```

and the second one contains this:

```
:companyName
:url
:country
:address
:zip
:founders
:industry
:isPrivate
```

Is it possible to easily merge the contents of the second file into the first one so it looks like this:

```
companyName   :companyName
url           :url
country       :country
address       :address
zip           :zip
founders      :founders
industry      :industry
isPrivate     :isPrivate
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, that depends on what you mean with `easily merge`. The way I'd go about to do it would be the following:

In the file with the commas, place the cursor at the beginning of the first line, hold `alt+shift` and press the down-arrow key until you reach the last line, this enables multiple cursors.

Press `shift+end` so that you mark all the contents on each line. Press `ctrl+c` to copy.

In the other file repeat the first procedure, enabling multiple cursors, but do not copy, instead press `end`so that you get the cursors to the end of each line, press `tab`or `space` to get most of the lines where you want them and then press `ctrl+v`.

Finally you'll need to fix some of the lines like the one containing `zip`.

Comment: I got it working in a slightly different way, I highlighted everything on file 2 and then pressed _ctrl+shift+l_ (last character as in laravel) , copied it and then  _ctrl+shift+l_ in file 1, pressed _end_ and pasted it. I tried your method after finding out how to do it, both ways worked fine :)